# How can I properly use bell pepper in my meat curry?

Tags: chili-peppers, chili

I use [this chili](https://www.lalteer.com/Crops/crops_item/23) to cook [meat curries](https://youtu.be/wvar9ikcLF8). However, I have an exacerbated skin issue due to this chili ingestion. Therefore, I need a substitute that has the same fragrance but is not hot.

I tried to use green bell pepper. However, it doesn't work. Bell pepper is too juicy, and the fragrance fades away after cooking.

How can I properly use bell pepper in my meat curry?

Comment: What style of curry are you making? Curry is a broad term describing dishes from around the world.

Comment: Is the skin issue due to getting chili on your skin when cutting them or ingesting them?

Comment: I recognize that the duplicate target is about an allergy to both chilli and bell peppers, but it is obvious from the question that the OP is already aware of bell peppers being a potential substitute anyway, and looking for further options.

Comment: In general, don't edit questions so much that they invalidate existing answers. As an answer to your question, add it later in cooking maybe? And look for curry recipes that have bell pepper in them for ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the issue with the skin condition is due to the heat of your chili, I think the way to go is "piment vegetarien". It is improperly called vegetarian pepper due to its lack of heat, it's commonly found in French Antilles and French Guiana. To my knowledge there is no english term for those kind.
Lots of flavor, no heat, I think it's worth the try

I have found an example here:
https://arawakmarket.com/epicerie-fr/epicerie-salee-fr/sauces-and-condiments-fr/piment-vegetarien-en-morceaux-190g/?sl=en

And close species listed on the french wikipedia (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_vari%C3%A9t%C3%A9s_de_piment):

- Bahamian chili pepper (there are 2 kinds, one with heat, one without)
- Sweet Datil Pepper
- Aji dulce

Hope it was what you were looking for